# Arduino.Mk together with MightyCore

Tags: makefile

There's no end to my frustration trying to figure out how the arduino build system works -- despite my best efforts I just can't seem to grok it. Anyhow, I did this:

```
ALTERNATE_CORE_PATH=/path/to/MightyCore/avr
BOARD_TAG=324
...
```

`make show_boards` shows me several boards available, including `324`. Yet whenever I try to build my project, I get this error:

```
avr-g++: error: missing device or architecture after ‘-mmcu=’
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: what is after `-mmcu=`?

Comment: doesn't look like you use Arduino IDE or arduino-cli

Comment: I used Arduino.mk. I think I have managed to sort it out, just took a few extra Makefile options:

```
BOARD_TAG=324
MCU=atmega324a
VARIANT=standard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with the following Makefile options:

```
BOARD_TAG=324
MCU=atmega324a
VARIANT=standard
```